# Generating an entity from existing table not from console

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

First post ever here, after having been able to manage it with other people posts and answers.

I have created an event listener in which I need to create a "child" entity in order to add it to the "parent" entity's arrayCollection.
I've created entities before, am not getting error messages but it seems that the entity is never actually created nor added to the parent's entity arrayCollection obviously.

Have checked other posts, but it indicates how to create a new entity from the console and so doesn't help me much in this case.

The code is shown below.

I know I get into it as I can dump local variables. I can also see the `$entityEvent` object, but it never gets saved somehow.

Have done the following in case I had missed any change somewhere else in the project's code, just in case:

- Have tried persisting the entity using the entityManager instead of the objectManager.
- Have done a schema update in the DB.

```php
namespace App\Event\Listener;

# Doctrine Components
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

# App Components
use App\Entity\Api\Entity;
use App\Entity\Api\EntityEvent;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\PreUpdateEventArgs;

// Entity repository
// use App\Entity\Api\Repository\entityEventEntityRepository;

class EntityListener   {
    public $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)  {
        $this->em = $em;
    }


    public function postUpdate(Entity $entity, LifecycleEventArgs $event) {
        $objectManager = $event -> getObjectManager();

        $entityEvent = new entityEvent();
        $entityEvent -> setEntity($entity);
        $entityEvent -> setStatus($entity -> getStatus());

        $entity -> addEntityEvent($entityEvent);

        $objectManager -> persist($entityEvent);
        $objectManager -> flush();

    }

}
```

I would have expected the `$entityEvent` being persisted and flush in the DB and the $entity object adding it properly to it.

Instead nothing gets saved.

Why I don't get the expected behaviour?

Comment: Start by verifying that postUpdate is even being called i.e. do you have the listener properly registered.  Still won't work because postUpdate will be called on every entity so you will be trying to add your EntityEvent (poor name by the way) to all entities.  But even worse, once you flush the manager then postUpdate will be called again since you updated the original entity again.  Doctrine events are tricky.  Best to use a different approach completely.

Comment: I know that postUpdate is being called as I've managed to dump variables inside it.
Interesting about postUpdate being called again, had not read about that effect. Will see if I can find another way around this problem then. Thanks!
(Just for reference, the EntityEvent name is just for this post, my variable has another name entirely in the proper file)